# Express mongoose Query cannot set headers

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, error-handling

Does anyone know why this code gives me the error: "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"?
Is there something wrong with my Mongoose Queries?
Thanks for your help!!

```
router.post('/setriskbydate', (req, res) => {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var from = new Date(req.body.from);
    var to = new Date(req.body.to);

    var dates = getDates(from, to);

    User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, resp) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        if (resp) {
            var rideIds = resp.ride;
            for (let i = 0; i < rideIds.length; i++) {
                Ride.findOne({ _id: rideIds[i] }, (error, response) => {
                    if (error) {
                        res.send(error)
                    }
                    if (response) {
                        var busnumber = response.busnumber
                        var date = response.date.split('T')[0];
                        if (dates.includes(date)) {
                            console.log(response);
                            Ride.updateMany({ busnumber: busnumber, date: { "$regex": date }}, { risk: "high" }, (er, re) => {
                                if (er) {
                                    res.send(er);
                                }
                                if (re) {
                                    res.send(re);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })

            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Your code must be also getting executed even after the res.send(). Try using return res.send();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to `return` all your response statements so that the responses aren't sent more than once, including the headers which cannot be set again after a response.

```
return res.send(err);

...

return res.send(re);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but I keep getting the error message and my server breaks down... I added a return statement before every res.send().. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.. Because I am in a for loop I cant do res.send() because the function terminates then. I just replaced the last res.send() with something else and it worked.